# How to add multiple objects into a ModelAndView?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model, controller, validation

How to add multiple objects into the ModelAndView in a controller in Spring MVC 3 ? Is that possible?

Comment: Your comment on the answer implies that you have a specific problem. Could you please elaborate on it and update the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add attributes to the model in Spring using the `addAttribute()` method.  To add multiple attributes to the model just call the method multiple times.  The first argument supplied to `addAttribute` accepts the attribute's name and the second accepts the attributes value.

```
model.addAttribute("one", 1);
model.addAttribute("two", 2);
```

You could also add collections to the model.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("one");
list.add("two");
model.addAttribute("list", list);
```

[Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html#addAttribute%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: In my method i do :  **public ModelAndView GestionUsers(@ModelAttribute User user)**  and **ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("usersystem", userservice.getAllUsers());** So the liste of all users not appears just the object User is in the model

Comment: I did the same and the table appear in my page until i added a form where i add a user to database so the problem is that after adding the form the list Go ! that means my method accepts the attribut not the object